# Associating an icon with an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

Is it possible to associate an image as an attribute with an Object in Javascript like this? So far I have not been able to get it to work.

```
var spy={
  name: "Spy",
  life: true,
  voting: true,
  icon: new Image();
}
icon.src = "Images/testImage";
```

Comment: In addition to my answer, here's a friendly tip: Make yourself familiar with the development tools of your browser, first of all the console. It's probably accessible by pressing F12 on your keyboard and it should have helped you to debug this without anyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to access or modify an object's property, you can't just access the property name directly. You'll have to access an object property like this:

```
var spy={
  name: "Spy",
  life: true,
  voting: true,
  icon: new Image()
};
spy.icon.src = "Images/testImage";
```

Otherwise, if you had several "spy" objects, how were the JavaScript compiler to know which one's property you want to change?

There was also a syntax error (well, actually two):

1. the semicolon behind `new Image()`. You do not need and simply cannot put a semicolon in an object declaration that way.
2. you should however add a semicolon after the closing curly bracket, as it's a variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `src` property by `spy.icon.src`

```
var spy={
  name: "Spy",
  life: true,
  voting: true,
  icon: new Image()
};
spy.icon.src = "Images/testImage";
```

If you try to access the `src` property like `icon.src = "Images/testImage";` you will get an error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: icon is not defined"

as the icon is not declared or refered anywhere in the code. `icon` is a property of the `spy` object.